# Populate 'new' files from Windows context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, context-menu, gimp

### SOLVED:

Please read the answer to see the full solution.

### Possible Error Messages:

Gimp XFC image plug-In could not open image.

### Main Question(s):

Windows 10 Context Menu (<kbd>right-click</kbd>/<kbd>apps button</kbd>→`New`→`XCF File`: How do I populate new files with data?
How do I make the default XCF file a blank image of a predefined size of my choosing?

### What I have done:

1. Go to `Start`→ `Windows Administrative tools` → `Registry Editor` (Or hit <kbd>Win</kbd> and type `regedit` <kbd>enter</kbd>.  Press `yes` to run with administrative privileges.
2. Browse to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xcf`→<kbd>right-click</kbd>/<kbd>apps button</kbd>→`New > Key`→Type `ShellNew` <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
   <kbd>right-click</kbd>/<kbd>apps button</kbd>→`New > String Value` <kbd>enter</kbd>→Type `NullFile`→<kbd>enter</kbd>→Type `1` <kbd>enter</kbd>.
   [image: A picture of the result of following the steps seen above: "start, r-e-g, enter, left, spacebar, ctrl plus el, type from here: Computer backslash HKEY underbar CLASSES underbar ROOT backslash dot xcf: finish typing, enter, apps button en kay, all-one-word with uppercase S and N--type from here: ShellNew: finish typing, enter, apps button en es, all-one-word with uppercase N and F--type from here: NullFile: finish typing, enter, 1, enter, to exit regedit press Alt+F4. Win plus dee to show the desktop, apps button en gee to create a new gimp file, enter enter to open it and receive the error message.]
3. At the desktop I right-click and press N (new file) and then G (Gimp Image)...  The new file is created.  I open the file, and I get the unpunctuated error message: "Gimp XFC image plug-In could not open image."  Gimp is now open with no file!

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Start`→`Regedit` <kbd>enter</kbd>→`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xcf`→<kbd>right-click</kbd>/<kbd>apps button</kbd>→`New > Key`→Type `ShellNew` <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
   <kbd>right-click</kbd>/<kbd>apps button</kbd>→`New > String Value` <kbd>enter</kbd>→Type `NullFile`→<kbd>enter</kbd>→Type `1` <kbd>enter</kbd>.
2. Open regedit again and you should already be at `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xcf\ShellNew`.  Create a `new string value` (<kbd>right-click</kbd>/<kbd>apps button</kbd>→`New > String Value`→Type `FileName` <kbd>enter</kbd>→<kbd>enter</kbd>→type `New GIMP Image.xcf` <kbd>enter</kbd>.
3. Open gimp.  Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new file using your favorite template (select your favorite template from the drop-down menu that appears or just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and type `1280` then <kbd>tab</kbd> and type `720` <kbd>enter</kbd> for my favorite, which is HD).  Now, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select everything and delete it.  Type the file location into into the address bar that appears then press <kbd>enter</kbd> to browse there `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates`.
5. Now, type the following file name and press enter to save the image: `New Gimp Image.xcf`.
6. At the desktop, <kbd>right click</kbd> or press the <kbd>apps key</kbd> and go to `New file > Gimp Image`.

Result: The new file is created and should be an exact duplicate of the template file in the Windows Templates directory!  Congratulations!

Comment: You said this is for Windows 10.  I have Windows 10.2004 and this does not work.